# Extract Decimal Numbers from A User input in python

Tags: python, windows

i want to get result like this

user types this => ( set my_number 4444 )
program prints this => (my_number => 4444)
currently i am dealing with this and i cant figure it out

```
number1 = raw_input ('enter your number > ')
print ('number =>  ' + number1);sleep(2)
```

Comment: remove `sleep()` from code,  or import same `from time import sleep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take :

```
number = raw_input("Enter your number:")
number = number.split(" ")[-1]
print("my_number => "+str(number))
```

Comment: Might want to `split` the input and only take the last element because the user is supposed to type "set my_number 4444"

Comment: yes you are right @timgeb, In that case this answer is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from time import sleep
number1 = raw_input ('enter your number > ')
print ('number =>  ' + re.search(r'\d+[\.\d+]*', number1).group());
sleep(2)
```

Check if this helps

Comment: if my number is 19.89 it prints my number as 19

Comment: You not mentioned about float numbers in question, please be expressible as much you are while adding in question, Updated answer please refer @PulkitSinghania